# Google script, empty array from fetched API

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script

I'm trying to fetch my ETH balance and transactions from etherscan.io website and I'm trying to use the same code I used before for another website. But it seems returning me an empty array, and also the error "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid."
This is the code:

```
function getTx() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var url = 'http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x49E81AA0cFE7eeA9738430212DC6677acF2f01a1&sort=asc';
  var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  var rows = [],
      array;

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    array = data[i];
    rows.push([array.timeStamp, array.from, array.to, array.value]); 
  }
  Logger.log(rows)

  askRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, rows.length, 3);
  askRange.setValues(rows);  

}
```

The logged "rows" is empty, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: just console json and data-log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a following modification?

#### Modification points :

1. There is data you want at `data.result`.
2. Number of columns of data is 4.

#### Modified script :

```
function getTx() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var url = 'http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x49E81AA0cFE7eeA9738430212DC6677acF2f01a1&sort=asc';
  var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var rows = [],
      array;
  for (i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) { // Modified
    array = data.result[i];
    rows.push([array.timeStamp, array.from, array.to, array.value]); 
  }
  Logger.log(rows)
  askRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, rows.length, 4); // Modified
  askRange.setValues(rows);  
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes, it works! Shame on me I forgot to add the "result" to data. You also modified the "array =" row, maybe better to add the comment there also :) thanks a lot

Comment: @AlxMrx Thank you, too.